# Multilevel Modelling: Convergence Problems in models with sparse level-1 data when adding random slopes

Tags: mixed-model, glmm

I'm working on my Masters Thesis and I'm encountering an issue regarding model convergence.

A bit on the background: the thesis is about utilitarian decision making in moral dilemma situations and its relation with dark personality traits (such as Psychopathy, Narcissism etc.) and potential moderating effects of characteristics of these situations (e.g., whether the utilitarian choice serves oneself as well or not). This yields a bit of an unorthodox multilevel design, as the data are sort of "pseudo-nested": no repeated measures, no "genuine" clustering, just a single survey with 8 Dilemma Situations, which are modelled as nested within the Person ID.

Sample is thus:

Level 2: N = 850ish Participants

Level 1: N = 8 Dilemma Situations (4/4 self-interested/not)

My Model so far is:

`lmer(UtilScore ~ self_interest * involvement + DC_total + (1 |ID), data = MA_data_long)`

self_interest and involvement are level-1 variables (situation variables), DC_total is a personality trait.

I want to add a random effect for self_interest and a subsequent cross-level interaction with DC to see whether DC (and other traits) can explain variance in the effect of self_interest (or involvement). Doing so leads to convergence issues with negative eigenvalues.

The obvious culprit is the data sparseness on level 1 (only 4 data points per ID for self_interest = 1 and self_interest = 0). I checked whether duplicating the data (i.e., simulating 16 items for the outcome instead of 8) would change anything, and it does.

Level of measurement:

- Traits (e.g. DC) is metric
- Outcome is ordinal (4-point-likert scale)
- self_interest and involvement are binary

I've ignored the ordinal outcome so far and wanted to later check with a GLMM whether accounting for that has any impact.

So the question(s) is:

are there any ways of working around these issues? Can maybe GLMMs with appropriate link handle this any better? And, is it even appropriate to model the research question like this, given that slope estimates are probably really unstable?

And as a follow up: any suggestions on how to model these moderations instead?

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious but .... You wrote "I want to add a random effect for self_interest and a subsequent cross-level interaction with DC to see whether DC (and other traits) can explain variance in the effect of self_interest (or involvement). "   Isn't that what your interaction in the fixed effects does?

Comment: @Peter Flom thanks for the answer! Can I include interaction terms between a level-1 and level-2 predictor as simple interaction of fixed effects? I might be mistaken but I thought I had to model a random slope for the effect of interest, and led the context variable explain variation in its slope. In other words: is it sensible to model cross-level interactions without specifying a random effect?

Comment: Now I'm not sure!  But I think it is. Someone else will know.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with the multilevel model approach you need random intercept of participant in any case because that takes care of the non-independence of your data points.

About the random slope: there's a relatively recent [simulation study](https://academic.oup.com/esr/article-abstract/35/2/258/5306121) suggesting that you should always include random slope of the level 1 predictor if you include a cross-level interaction, otherwise you get inflated estimates. So there's that.

(So you don't need to include the random slope of the interaction, just the random slope of the level 1 predictor in the interaction, and the interaction itself as a fixed effect).

However with categorical level 1 predictors and so few level 1 observations a lmer model with a random slope is probably not going to converge.

Not sure how to solve this. These are my intuitions, which may be off: You could try using some optimizers, or maybe a bayesian model, which are often considered to work better with sparse data. Also, I've seen glmmTMB function make models converge when lmer doesn't. You could also move to a single-level model using clustered standard errors to deal with the non-independence.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried different optimizers in different model configurations and sadly this doesn't change much. I will try glmmTMB as well as ordinal regression (using clmm) next!